# Suddenly moveActiveSheet returns an error - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am getting the following error:

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with
> id . . .

when I try to execute a script on a Google sheet.
The script worked fine until today.

I believe the problem occurs between these two lines:

```
  var newTab = sheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  sheet.moveActiveSheet(1);
```

because at the time of the error the duplicate sheet has been created
but has not yet been moved to the first position.

Is it possible that the `"moveActiveSheet"` command suddenly can not
find the new active sheet that has just been created?

If so, is there some other way to do this?

Comment: Seems to be the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65313042/exception-error-with-google-script-when-i-tried-to-use-moveactivesheet). I answered that question with a Sheets API workaround.

Answer (score 1):

### There seems to be a bug and it has already been reported.

The issue has been already reported today (15th of December) in the **[IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175625775)** by 13 users (as of now).

Click on the star ⭐ icon to the top/upper-left corner of the [webpage](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175625775) to make the issue more popular in order for Google to fix it sooner.

This [workaround solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65313463/11225291) might be useful, I haven't tested it, but you can give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an internal error in the moveActiveSheet line.

I have found a work around for the problem.
In the script comment out the moveActiveSheet line as shown here:

```
  var newTab = sheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  // sheet.moveActiveSheet(1);
  sheet.renameActiveSheet(newTabName);
```

This will result in the new tab being misplaced.
You can manually move it to the first position.

Google claims to be working on a fix for this problem.
See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175625775

Comment: I don't believe this is a workaround . You just said yourself you need to `manually change the position`. If you do this manually then it is not solving your script issue. Also the best approach to duplicate a sheet is to use the `sheet.copyTo(spreadsheet)` method which ensures that the right sheet is selected either by its name or position.

Answer (score 0):

### The [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/175625775) occurs when `pos` in `sheet.moveActiveSheet(pos)` is `1`

While the bug is being fixed, as a workaround, instead of e.g. moving the second sheet to the first position, you can move the first sheet to the second position.

Because

`sheet.moveActiveSheet(2);`

still works.

Comment: I think that this issue should be closed but I do not know how to do so.