# Exception Error with Google Script when I tried to use moveActiveSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I keep getting "Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id " while trying to run moveActiveSheet to move a sheet in tab with index 4 to index 1. This just happened very lately. I had been using my code for months before this happened. Does any body is facing the same thing?

My code is below

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//==========================================
//Arrange the Sheet
// Store all the worksheets in this array
var sheetNameArray = [];
var sheets = ss.getSheets();
for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
};
sheetNameArray.sort();

var sheetName = sheetNameArray[0]; //This tab is currently at index 4
var getSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
Logger.log(getSheet.getIndex());
ss.setActiveSheet(getSheet);
ss.moveActiveSheet(1); //Trying to move it to index 1 but exception was thrown
```

Comment: I have the same problem.Started right before the google server down event on 12/14, worked fine briefly after the servers were up. Now not working again. I transitioned that part of my script to Sheets API.

Comment: See the first post regarding this issue: [Suddenly moveActiveSheet returns an error - Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65311243/suddenly-getting-google-scripts-error-in-a-script-that-has-been-working-fine-for/65313516#65313516)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a work-around that worked for me, I loop through the sorted array. I used .batchUpdate from `Sheets API`. You have to enable it from advanced services first: Resources > Advanced Google Services

```
function move_sheet_func(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  //==========================================
  //Arrange the Sheet
  // Store all the worksheets in this array
  var sheetNameArray = [];
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheetNameArray.push(sheets[i].getName());
  };
  sheetNameArray.sort();
  
  var sheetName = sheetNameArray[0]; //This tab is currently at index 4
  var getSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var sheetsreq = [];
  //create requests for each sheet to be moved to its index as sorted
  sheetNameArray.forEach(function (name, indx) {
    sheetsreq.push({ updateSheetProperties: {
      fields: "index, title",
      properties: {
        index: indx,
        title: name,
        sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(name).getSheetId()
      }
    } });
  });
  var req = { "requests": sheetsreq };
  console.log(JSON.stringify(req));
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(req, ss.getId());

}
```

Comment: yes, this is what I found as a work-around too. Thank you.

Comment: @HaiTruong I thought they fixed it the very next day. Is the moveActiveSheet function still not working for you?

Comment: I haven't check it lately. The Sheets API works for me so I just went ahead and use it.